# Rails & Redcarpet: uninitialized constant Redcarpet::Render when used in ApplicationHelper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railscasts, redcarpet

I'm following along the RailsCasts episode for [Syntax Highlighting Revised](http://railscasts.com/episodes/207-syntax-highlighting-revised). I updated my ApplicationHelper to look like so:

```
require 'redcarpet'

module ApplicationHelper
  class HTMLwithPygments < Redcarpet::Render::HTML
    def block_code(code, language)
      Pygments.highlight(code, lexer:language)
    end
  end

  def markdown(text)
    renderer = HTMLwithPygments.new(hard_wrap: true, filter_html: true)
    options = {
      autolink: true,
      no_intra_emphasis: true,
      fenced_code_blocks: true,
      lax_html_blocks: true,
      strikethrough: true,
      superscript: true
    }
    Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, options).render(text).html_safe
  end
end
```

However, my web app returns

```
Routing Error

uninitialized constant Redcarpet::Render

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.11 and Redcarpet responds fine in rails console. I've originally didn't include `require 'redcarpet'` but I followed the instructions on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085053/unitialized-constant-in-model) but it didn't help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I removed my `Gemfile.lock` and did `bundle install` again and it worked perfectly.

Comment: BTW it might just have been that you needed to restart your server. This was the case for me.

Comment: I tried that a few times and it didn't help but I'll keep the advice in mind in case of future strangeness. :)

Comment: @callum that was the case for me, in the rails console `reload!` didn't do it, I had to stop and restart it.